# How to customize header with Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, pdf, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I'm currently working on a pdf document using `Rmarkdown` on `RStudio` but I'm very much confused about to how to customize my YAML section. This is my actual code:

```
---
title: "The very basics of R"
author: "Alejandro C."
date: "March, 2020"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: true

mainfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \posttitle{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \predate{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \postdate{\end{flushleft}}  

---
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

- Use a bigger fontsize in my title (for example, 14) and boldface it
- Use 12 fontsize for author and date
- Use 11 fontsize for my document (I don't know if this must be specified in the YAML section)

I'm new on this topic so I really don't know where to start besides the [R Markdown Reference Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjr2ceQuqfnAhVSd6wKHU5cBHEQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Frstudio.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F03%2Frmarkdown-reference.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2M4P5cwjjqyudM0DwsOy_W). Any help and advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Once you get past a certain point with customising PDF output, you are using Latex, not Rmarkdown, so you're probably better off looking at questions like [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263676/modifying-maketitle-with-the-titling-package) on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60023695/10215301), which doesn't require you to edit `.tex` file.

Comment: @Marius is right: this is more of a LateX than an RMarkdown question. You can use LateX commands where ever you want, when you knit a PDF - just need to escape some characters.

Answer (score 7):

You can include `LaTeX` commands in the YAML section, so that you can change the size, shape, and face of the fonts. Note that you needs to duplicate `\` (a backslash) in the YAML section.

In the MWE below, the following commands are used:

- **`\textit{}`**

  - `\\textit{}` in YAML
  - makes the letters italic
- **`\textbf{}`**

  - `\\textbf{}` in YAML
  - makes the letters boldface
- **`\fontsize{14pt}{3pt}\\selectfont`**

  - `\\fontsize{14pt}{3pt}\\selectfont` in YAML
  - makes the letters 14pt with a 3pt line feed

As suggested by @Marius [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59958677/how-to-customize-header-with-rmarkdown/60023695#comment106035897_59958677), you may want to customize the output further beyond simple markdown syntax. So, it's better to set `keep_tex: true` for such an occasion.

## MWE

```
---
title: "\\fontsize{14pt}{3pt}\\selectfont \\textbf{\\textit{The very basics of R}}"
author: "\\fontsize{12pt}{3pt}\\selectfont Alejandro C."
date: "\\fontsize{12pt}{3pt}\\selectfont March, 2020"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: true
    keep_tex: true
mainfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \posttitle{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \predate{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \postdate{\end{flushleft}}  
---

# Lorem Ipsum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.
```

## Output

[image]